# Hibernate design pattern question

Tags: java, hibernate

Im working with Hibernate. It works great. However, say that I have a class that corresponds to a database table with only getters and setters and toString, equal methods. Now I would like to add some more methods for helping purpose, for example, say that I would like to get the creationdate with some added description text as shown below.

```
public class Client {
        private long id;
        private Calendar creationDate;
        protected String password;

            public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Calendar getCreationDate() {
            return creationDate;
        }

        public void setCreationDate(Calendar creationDate) {
            this.creationDate = creationDate;
        }

        ..
        .. some other getters and setters that corresponding to SQL columns 

        //Here I would like to have some help methods. Is it recommended to put it here?
        public String getCreationDateInSecs() {
            return "Date in secs: " + creationDate.getTimeInMillis * 1000;
        }
    }
```

The question is: Where should I place this method?

Should I add it in the same class as the Value Object or should I place it somewhere else? I would like to know the best practice if you know what I mean =)

Best regards

Comment: Okey, I didnt knew that. Thanks, I will do it from now on =)

Comment: @James P. not obligated of course. That's why I used "should" rather than "must" :) @kungcc - you can do this on your previous questions as well.

Comment: No worries Bozho. I was just adding to your reply :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bozho basically outlined two possible approaches: *rich model* and *anemic model*, and suggested a rich model as more OOPish. I'll advocate an anemic approach here.

The functionality you describe looks like a responsibility of a presentation layer. I think it would be better to put it into UI-related classes rather than into the domain model.

Putting it into domain model looks harmless as long as the logic is as simple as

```
return "Date in secs: " + creationDate.getTimeInMillis * 1000;
```

However, imagine that you got an additional requirement to return a localized description. You will have to add dependencies on localization facilities to your domain model, that increases coupling of your code.

So, it's better to keep responsibilities of different layer separated.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will read more about these patterns.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely no problem in adding the method in the entity. It is where it belongs, because it operates on the internal state of the object.

You can make an utility method, like `ClientUtils.getCreationDateInSeconds(client)`, but that's rather non-OOP.

Comment: I agree with Bozho. You could move the method to a utility class but then it makes the code lapse back to procedural. It's when a method operates on something besides the internal state that the question becomes important and the idea of a service pops up. I suggest you look up anemic and rich domain model as there are various opinions on the subject (I personally prefer anemic to keep code in the domain model to a minimum).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will read more about these patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about mixing your entities with many methods like this, and you have many DAO methods,  you may consider using the Aspect oriented approach.

It will allow you to separate the pure entity stuff, the DAO stuff, and other utility methods in separate "aspects"  without breaking OO principles.

Spring and AspectJ does this well.
If you want a quick example of how stuff is implemented take a look here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/architecture.html